# Load .dump file to neo4j database (neo4j server community edition)

Tags: neo4j, load

I'm trying to load the data contained in a .dump file (that i received from a friend) to the neo4j db of my neo4j community server instance.
I'm trying running the following command:

```
sudo neo4j-admin load --from=/usr/local/instance2/backup/graph-dbms-unemployment.dump --database=neo4j --force="true"
```

I get the following error:

```
Unmatched arguments from index 0: 'load', '--from=/usr/local/instance2/backup/graph-dbms-unemployment.dump', '--database=neo4j', '--force=true'
Did you mean: database load or database upload or dbms set-default-admin?
```

How can i load the data that is contained into this dump file to my neo4j db?
It's not too clear to me how the process of importing data from a .dump file to the neo4j db works.

Can someone help me with this? I really need some help to fix this issue.

Thanks for the support and for the help that you will give me :)

I tried reading several neo4j forums and also running the command with all the possible syntaxes that I was aware of.

Comment: You should probably ask at https://discord.com/channels/787399249741479977/854675261635428353. The operation of `neo4j-admin` is highly dependent on the versions (and editions) of neo4j used for dumping and loading, so you should be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested various methods from docker (cli) and desktop application web browser

- loading dump
- overriding neo4j default db

CE edition cannot load dump at least version 5.7 locally (version 4.x may be different)

This is blocked at permissions level of db root account. So it is intended by the developer.

- You can possibly load a CSV and rebuild the db manually
- What you can do is loading Cloud hosted Aura db (less data control). It is free. Then connect with bolt.
- As an eventual fallback for a Proof of Concept you can run a docker instance of memgraph it should be fairly similar, less support obviously. https://memgraph.com/ (bolt support enabled, has graphic desktop)